# Extract unique elements of each group of factor

Tags: r

Say I have a factor `myfac <- as.factor(c("A","A","B","B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "A","A","B","B", "C", "D", "D"))`.

I want to extract unique elements of this factor (not the levels). So the result I want is: `A B C D A B C D`. How can I get this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
rle(as.character(myfac))$values
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `head` and `tail` to compare current and previous value :

```
myfac[c(1, which(tail(myfac, -1) != head(myfac, -1)) + 1)]
#[1] A B C D A B C D
#Levels: A B C D
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
myfac[!duplicated(rleid(myfac))]
#[1] A B C D A B C D
```